# Read Exchange Server 2003 account emails

Tags: c#, exchange-server

Working on application that reads emails.
Is there a way besides webdav to get all emails from exchange server 2003 to my local machine. 
The problem with webdav is that it does not get's the body of Undelivered emails.

```
CredentialCache creds = new CredentialCache();
            creds.Add(new Uri(a), "NTLM",
                new NetworkCredential("xxxxx", "xxxxxx", "xxxxx.com"));

            List<Mail> unreadMail = new List<Mail>();
            string reqStr =

            @"<?xml version=""1.0""?>
                <g:searchrequest xmlns:g=""DAV:"">
                    <g:sql>
                        SELECT
                            ""urn:schemas:mailheader:from"",
                            ""urn:schemas:mailheader:to"",
                            ""urn:schemas:httpmail:textdescription""

                        FROM
                            ""http://xxxx.com/exchange/xxxx/Inbox/""
                        WHERE  

                             ""urn:schemas:httpmail:subject"" = 'Undeliverable: xxxx'                               

                        </g:sql>
                </g:searchrequest>";



            byte[] reqBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(reqStr);


            HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(a);
            request.Credentials = creds;
            request.Method = "SEARCH";
            request.ContentLength = reqBytes.Length;
            request.ContentType = "text/xml";
            request.Timeout = 300000;
            using (Stream requestStream = request.GetRequestStream())
            {
                try
                {
                    requestStream.Write(reqBytes, 0, reqBytes.Length);
                }
                catch
                {
                }
                finally
                {
                    requestStream.Close();
                }
            }
            HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
            using (Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream())
            {
                try
                {
                    XmlDocument document = new XmlDocument();
                    document.Load(responseStream);


                    XmlNamespaceManager nsmgr = new XmlNamespaceManager(document.NameTable);
                    nsmgr.AddNamespace("a", "DAV:");
                    nsmgr.AddNamespace("b", "urn:uuid:c2f41010-65b3-11d1-a29f-00aa00c14882/");
                    nsmgr.AddNamespace("c", "xml:");
                    nsmgr.AddNamespace("d", "urn:schemas:mailheader:");
                    nsmgr.AddNamespace("e", "urn:schemas:httpmail:");


                    XmlNodeList responseNodes = document.GetElementsByTagName("a:response");
                    foreach (XmlNode responseNode in responseNodes)
                    {

                        XmlNode uriNode = responseNode.SelectSingleNode("child::a:href", nsmgr);
                        XmlNode propstatNode = responseNode.SelectSingleNode("descendant::a:propstat[a:status='HTTP/1.1 200 OK']", nsmgr);
                        if (propstatNode != null)
                        {
                            // read properties of this response, and load into a data object
                            XmlNode fromNode = propstatNode.SelectSingleNode("descendant::d:from", nsmgr);
                            XmlNode descNode = propstatNode.SelectSingleNode("descendant::e:textdescription", nsmgr);
                            XmlNode toNode = propstatNode.SelectSingleNode("descendant::d:to", nsmgr);


                            // make new data object

                            Mail mail = new Mail();
                            if (uriNode != null)
                                mail.Uri = uriNode.InnerText;
                            if (fromNode != null)
                                mail.From = fromNode.InnerText;
                            if (descNode != null)
                                mail.Body = descNode.InnerText;
                            if (toNode != null)
                                mail.To = toNode.InnerText;
                            unreadMail.Add(mail);

                        }
                    }
                    var ac = unreadMail;

                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    string msg = e.Message;
                }
                finally
                {

                    responseStream.Close();
                }
            }
```

in the output xml i get empty text description for undelivered emails:

```
<a:status>HTTP/1.1 404 Resource Not Found</a:status><a:prop><e:textdescription /></a:prop></a:propstat></a:response>
```

Comment: There are several ways (depending on the configuration of the Exchange server etc.)... please show some code... what have you tried ? what exactly is not working ?

Comment: @Yahia view what have done....

Comment: thanks for the update... I suspect that the "body" is potentially "disguised" as an attachment... please see my answer below...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see several options to communicate with Exchange servers - WebDAV is rather hard to use and is not well supported in later version (2010), MS provides EWS but these don't work with older versions.

From my POV you can use any of the following components (commercial!):

- http://www.independentsoft.de/webdavex/index.html (WebDAV-based)
- http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/home.htm (COM- / Extended MAPI-based)
- http://www.afterlogic.com/mailbee-net/imap-component (IMAP4-based)

Another point:

When handling `Undeliverable` mails I made the experience that the body is sometimes provided as an attachment - in WebDAV this needs to be accessed via the `X-MS-ENUMATT` verb (but BEWARE: specific "attachments" like winmail.dat are automagically "decoded" by Outlook on display).

Comment: well thanks for your response, but is there any open source lib for free. Can I use webdav to get the email attachment an get it from there.

Comment: @AI25 I don't know of any free opensource library for this... in Exchange WebDAV protocol IIRC there is a verb name `ENUMATT` or similar which can help... check the Exchange docs on MSDN for that... BUT if the attachment is `winmail.dat` then that has an undocumented format!

Answer (score 1):

you can try sending HTTP request to the server same way as OWA does (specifying mail ID in it of course) - and then you will get HTML you can parse.

also - check if original message is in attachments array of the "undelivered" email.